# Issues with multiple row deletion in Cassandra with java

Tags: java, cassandra

I am having a Casandra DB modeled in such a way the the data_time will be the row Key. Row Key is in the format (yyyy_mm_dd_hh). This has been modeled as per the application needs.

There might be around 700K rows with the same row Key and hence when I try to delete the rows, I get a rpc_timeout exception when I query again. When I searched, I found that it is because SS Table might get corrupted. I do not want to run nodetool also because the deletion part will be automated through a batch.

I tired using Astyanax API from Netflix, but no luck. I am trying to delete records using a plan delete query from Java.

Could anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Can you provide details on the cluster setup, data model and client code?

Comment: Cluster is set up based on 4 nodes. Key Space has replication factor 1 and then data model set up is given below:                                     CREATE TABLE user_events(rowkey text,uuid text,values text>,PRIMARY KEY ((rowkey), uuid));                                                                              Client Code is a simplle java program that has connection open using datastax API to execute the delete query.

Comment: Interesting observation is that the rpc_timeout happens only when I do a select on the entire table in cqlsh. The table still takes in inserts/deletes and also select on a particular rowKey level. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your deletes (and reads, for that matter) is that you are performing a huge request that is not completing with the Cassandra timeout (default is 10 seconds).

Instead, try to narrow down the number of rows that you are deleting by specifying the `uuid` together with the `rowkey`.

So instead of:

```
cqlsh> DELETE FROM user_events WHERE rowkey='2015_02_08_14' ;
```

try this:

```
cqlsh> DELETE FROM user_events WHERE rowkey='2015_02_08_14' AND uuid = '5ee9d850-af44-11e4-9822-12e3f512a338';
```

Comment: If that is the case, then my client should get affected, right? Why does the server seem to have the SS Tables corrupted :( After I execute the bulk delete, I am facing issue with server side only(Executing a select count on the whole table) throws rpc_timeout. I tried executing count on entire table even after a day or so, but I got rpc_timeout eve after that. The count * only worked after I truncated the whole table :(

Comment: The client times out when you perform a SELECT on the whole table because it is the equivalent of a full table scan meaning it has to get ALL the rows from ALL the nodes and may not return within the timeout period.

Comment: A SELECT COUNT behaves in the same manner, i.e. it goes through all the partitions on all the nodes.